# Traversing a file in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, bioinformatics

I am a newbie to UNIX so bear with me please..  I have a long file that looks like this:

```
0       MitoT217C       0       217

0       MitoG228A       0       228

0       MitoC295T       0       295

0       MitoC458T       0       458
```

There is no header in this file. The first column represents chromosome number from 1-22 and the X and Y chromosomes. I want to extract data only for chromosome number 22 and X chromosome and put in a separate file. I know how to do the latter but Im confused on how to get data for only these two chromosomes.

Comment: Using a shell script, python, perl, other ? Please give us more details.

Comment: @ManuelSelva For a lot of people, UNIX and shell scripting are synonyms. :)

Comment: isn't this a question for superuser?

Comment: @Tim ok ;-) Even knowing that, can I add the shell tag to this question ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva I would say go for it. It seems to me like what the OP wants.

Comment: @ManuelSelva UNIX shell script

Comment: @Tim Yet the fact that lots of people are mistaken does not make it so. Unix/Linux employs a lot of shell scripting, and much shell scripting is done on Unix/Linux, but they are not the same thing. With appropriately loose definitions, even Powershell or (aaaccckkk..) cmd on Windows is "shell scripting", not to mention ports of Unix-y shells to Windows...

Comment: @user3108631 You say "The first column ... from 1-22", yet your example shows data with the first column being 0, which needlessly confuses the question...

Comment: @twalberg I never claimed it is right. Was trying to help. Reading between the lines is a good skill to have on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

- GNU grep: `egrep '^(22|X)' oldfile > newfile`
- GNU sed: `sed -r '/^(22|X)/!d' oldfile > newfile`